# Requery form after relinking tables

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am developing an MS-Access application with the data sitting in a separate backend database (Also MS-Access). The main form contains a button to open a settings dialog, an exit button (both in the form header) and a navigation control with a number of tabs showing subforms in form details. The settings dialog is a popup. In the dialog the user can change the path to the backend database and all linked tables will be relinked automatically if the user saves settings. This works all very well.

However, after closing the dialog, requerying the active subform has no effect, only if I close and reopen the form (e.g., by clicking a different tab) would it show data from the new (relinked database).

And I think this has somehow nothing to do with my relinking vba code.

I tried to open my subform directly and used the Linked Table Manager, with the same result. Hitting the refresh button on the ribbon does nothing, only when I change to design view and back to form view, the data in the form would be updated.

I also tried different combinations of repaint, refresh and requery, but to no avail.

I use requery extensively in my code and it works well, but it seems not after a simple reconnect of linked tables. The different backend databases have the exact same structure, they are just duplicates with some records removed to have test cases.

What's going on here?

Regards Oliver

Comment: Normally, during relinking, you will have no bound forms open, or the relinking may fail. So, close all bound forms, relink, open a bound form - the data of the current link will be viewed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Then I have to change my layout so that the settings form (which is unbound) replaces the main form. I was hoping ther would be another solution.

Comment: There are several way to manage this. The method in the answer from Jeffrey may be one, though neither have I tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [Jeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4175929/jeffrey), Your answer pointed me in the right direction. I wasn't aware of the `SourceObject`property. This is, however, a property of the subform control that holds the actual subform. In my special case of a navigation control, it is the navigation subform control that holds the active subform which is defined on the tab as `NavigationTargetName`.

So my code looks as below:

```
' ContentContainer is the NavigationSubform control
srcObjStr = Me.ContentContainer.SourceObject
Me.ContentContainer.SourceObject = ""
UpdatePathes 'Relinking
Me.ContentContainer.SourceObject = srcObjStr
```

There isn't even the need to requery. Very nice.

Regards Oliver

Comment: Perfect, only thing I would add is that if you have an unexpected crash during UpdatePathes your SourceObject will still be "" when you reopen the DB. So it may be a good idea to always set that when you open the form to ensure you don't cause an error.

Comment: Good point! As I use [vbWatchdog](https://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.asp), another solution would be to have `ErrEx.Catch` and `ErrEx.Finally` blocks in my code. In the finally block I would reset the SourceObject to its initial value. However, vbWatchdog is not free.

Comment: For a pure VBA approach to try-catch, look into this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94462).

Answer (score 2):

I think if you use the SourceObject property of the subform instead of binding them you could force an update without closing your forms.

```
Form_myForm.mySubForm1.SourceObject = ""
Form_myForm.mySubForm2.SourceObject = ""
```

run your relink routines

```
Form_myForm.mySubForm1.SourceObject = "mySubFormQuery1"
Form_myForm.mySubForm2.SourceObject = "mySubFormQuery2"

Form_myForm.mySubForm1.requery
Form_myForm.mySubForm2.requery
```

This is just speculation, I've never had a situation where I needed to relink at runtime, but I think it should work.